# Vector of pointers saving a pointer to a vector of ints

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

just wondering if you can point to a pointer that points to a vector of ints. And save the pointer that points to a vector of ints. Here's the code I'm trying to pull off.
Probably dosen't make sense but I'm trying to make it work for a while now, bare with me. But I want to pull this way somehow.

```
int n, q;
cin >> n >> q;
vector <int*> ar;

for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    vector< int >  *vec;

    for(int j = 0;j<k;j++){
        (*(vec+j)).push_back(cin.get());

    }
    ar.push_back(&(vec));


}
```

Thanks for the possible help. Haven't seen this asked in here, just things a bit different than this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your data structure should look like. Based on the last line, `ar` should have the type `vector<vector<int>*>`. But I don't get what you're trying to achieve with `vec+j`, since that will only create a garbage pointer value

Comment: I want the content of that pointer. But i undersatnd what you are saying its wrong.

Comment: `vector< int >  *vec;` is not initialized, so there's your first problem. And `ar.push_back(&(vec));` will add a dangling pointer to your vector, as `vec` goes out of scope right afterwards

Comment: Thank you, im going to think about it to really understand what you just said. To many concepts clashing into each other. thanks!!

Comment: Your question - "wondering if you can" - is a question that can be answered with simply "Yes" or "No".  In your case, _yes_.  Is that really the question you want an answer to?

Comment: Yes, it is enough for me. Pushes me to keep trying. I think answers don't help me unless i have tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're trying to achieve here:

```
int n, q;
cin >> n >> q;
vector<vector<int>*> ar;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>;
    for(int j = 0;j<k;j++){
        vec->push_back(cin.get());
    }
    ar.push_back(vec);    
}
// do not forget to delete the inner vectors before removing them from ar!
```

What you end up with is a vector `ar` that contains pointers to other vectors which in turn contain `int`s.

I don't see though why you would want to store pointers here at all, a nested vector works fine:

```
int n, q;
cin >> n >> q;
vector<vector<int>> ar;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int j = 0;j<k;j++){
        vec.push_back(cin.get());
    }
    ar.push_back(vec);    
}
```

Comment: `vector<vector<int>*> ar;`. Can you write what it is exactly. Three hours ago I didn't know what a vector was. Is it a vector of pointers that point to a vector of ints?

Comment: @Drigy Read it from the inside out: `vector<int>` is, well, a vector of integers. `vector<int>*` is a pointer to that. `vector<vector<int>*>` is a vector contatining said pointers. And the full thing declares the variable `ar` which has that type. So `ar` is a vector of pointers to vectors of integers.

Comment: In the second version, the outer vector doesn't cotain pointers, but the actual inner vectors themselves. That's a lot easier to keep track of since you don't need to remember to `delete` them when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: WOW, you read my mind I was thinking about that. haha

Answer (score 0):

in C/C++ you can point to litteraly anyting, heck event to nothing or to itself (`void*`) but if you wath to make a matrix just use `int a[][]` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>> m`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).